# Forcing one to stay while forcing one to leave?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> There is this word that means to force one to stay.
> that read backwards, means to force one to leave.

What is that word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be the word:

> **[NAB](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nab)** - which means 'arrest' or 'apprehend'. If a police officer 'nabs' a criminal, they are *forced to stay* in a prison cell.

Reversed, this is:

> **[BAN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ban)** - which means 'prohibit' or 'expel'. If a pub landlord (or landlady) 'bans' a person from their establishment, they are *forced to leave* the premises and not return.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is what you mean but:

> TRAP is keeping someone.  PART is leaving them.

Comment: Great answer! But the only problem is, the second part of your answer doesn't have force involved.

Comment: Oh but it does. It you PART from someone, they are forced to leave you, as well.  They can't not.